# Windows 7 Backup Complains it can't backups two non-existent folders

Tags: windows-7, sql-server

I am running scheduled daily backups using Windows 7 Backup on my Windows 7 Ultimate Laptop. It constantly gives me the following errors in the backup log:

```
Backup encountered a problem while backing up file C:\Users\sqlExpress2k8\Contacts. Error:(The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002))
Backup encountered a problem while backing up file C:\Users\sqlExpress2k8\Searches. Error:(The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002))
```

The user sqlExpress is the user that my sql server processes run as. These folders do not actually exist on my file system, and there have been several reboots to rule out any issues of stuck file handles etc.

**Update:** I installed Denali CTP, and ran it as a different user and I get error messages for the same two folders in the users home directory. I recently reinstalled windows on my laptop and still get the error for the sql service user:

```
Backup encountered a problem while backing up file C:\Users\sql_denali_service\Contacts. Error:(The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002))
Backup encountered a problem while backing up file C:\Users\sql_denali_service\Searches. Error:(The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002))
```

Comment: System Image backup or File backup?

Comment: Moab, its a full scheduled backup, not an ad-hoc system image backup. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the SQL server process(es) off and re-running the backup. SQL may be telling Windows that those folders need to be backed up (even though they aren't there).

Comment: Josh, that really doesn't make much sense to me because those folder names seem "desktop-ish" However, I've stopped all my sql server instaneces and I'll see what the log says tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Justin Dearing, Hmm, you're right. For some reason I thought they were a folder further down (inside AppData). Why not just copy the contacts and searches folder from your profile or another users profile, if for nothing else but to satisfy Microsoft's vision of what should be inside a users profile?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer in a [tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/vinodk_sql/status/70048018996539392) by [Vinod Kumar](http://twitter.com/#!/vinodk_sql). He declined to post himself so I will self answer this question.

The second senario described in Microsoft [KB979281](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979281) tells you that this error can be ignored, as well as how to make it go away.